# How to determine the conversion path?

Tags: logistic, cart

A user interacts with X number of features before they go on to convert.  How do I  determine which features, **and in what order**, is the most common path to conversion?

For example, if I was doing this analysis for Amazon I would have a "viewed product page" feature and an "add to wishlist" feature.  My conversion would be a purchase.

I would like an output that says something like: The most common path to conversion is when a user views 3 items, adds something to a wishlist, and then views 1 more item.  I want to know the best order of events and the number of interactions with each feature.

A decision tree, or what JMP calls [Partition analysis](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Partition_Models.shtml#1175640), looks like it would be the perfect tool, but it doesn't take the order of events into account.  Logistic regression is similar.  It only takes the fact that an event happened into account and ignores the order in which the events occurred.

How do I do an analysis that gives me insight into the order of inputs and not just the presence of inputs?